# What is the data type of the Output matrix in the buildCostMatrix function?

Tags: opencv, histogram, opencv3.0, scilab

I am passing a Mat container in the function. But I am unaware of what will be the output. How shall I display the output? Because when I am displaying it as an image, it is showing a blank matrix. Please provide suggestions. Thank you in advance.

This is my code

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include"opencv2/shape.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


/**
 * @function main
 */
int main()
{
  Mat src, dst;
  Mat src1,dst1;
  /// Load image
  src = imread("photo.jpg" );
  src1= imread("photo1.jpg");
  if( !src.data )
    { return -1; }
  if( !src1.data )
    { return -1; }


    int bins = 256;
    int histSize[] = {bins};
    // Set ranges for histogram bins
    float lranges[] = {0, 256};
    const float* ranges[] = {lranges};
    // create matrix for histogram
    cv::Mat hist,hist1, out;
    int channels[] = {0};double k;
    int const hist_height = 256;
    cv::Ptr<HistogramCostExtractor> model = createChiHistogramCostExtractor(25,0.2f);
    cv::Mat3b hist_image = cv::Mat3b::zeros(hist_height, bins);
    cv::calcHist(&src, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);
    cv::calcHist(&src1, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist1, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);
    //double cost[256][256];
   // int costrows = std::max(hist.rows,hist1.rows)+nDummies;
    //out.create(costrows,costrows,CV_32F);
   cout << hist_height;


    model->buildCostMatrix(hist,hist1,out);
    normalize(out, out, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );


    cout << out;


cv::waitKey(); 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show at least some example code of what you've tried or at least as far as you've managed to get. Your question is currently too lacking in any detail for people to help. Be specific, show attempts and results.

Comment: I am passing 2 histograsm as input to the buildCostMatrix function {model->buildCostMatrix(hist,hist1,out);             cout<<out;}      I cannot post the entire code in comments.

Comment: You can always edit your question to provide more detail (recommended). That will also help others who might come across your question in the future too.

Comment: I have added my code. Here when I print the output matrix, I am getting huge range of float values. How to make a sensible output out of it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the cost matrix is: `CV_32FC1`, i.e. a single channel float matrix.

You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/shape/src/hist_cost.cpp) where `_costMatrix` is created as:

```
_costMatrix.create(costrows, costrows, CV_32FC1);
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you please help me regarding how to put it as an output. Because when I am printing it, I am getting a lot of float values.